# AnyLogic custom route in process modeling

Tags: routes, path, process, anylogic

In my process, the agents appear in the lower box.
Is there a way that I can specify the route they are taking from the lower box to the top box, so they dont use the shortest path (red), but my custom path (green)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way is to define an intermediary point that you would need your agents to go to before they move to the final destination, and this middle point would be in the path you want them to take.

Remember that anylogic internally always takes the shortest path, so you have no control over this with the basic anylogic elements

Comment: Agreed. Or you go full-out custom routing as explained in my tutorial here. Then, you have 100% control on everything (but it is not for the faint-hearted): https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiGJP0k1miFbQ0XfchiMK9nxj-qr42dyw